# behavioral model of an electronic device

Tags: filters

I have an assignment for the course entitled "Nonlinear System Identification," and I appreciate any help.

The below figure shows the model that I need to extract its parameters. we have been provided with 4 data vectors namely input_x, input_val_x, output_y, output_val_y to estimate the parameters and then evaluate out extracted parameters.

I have divided the problem into small signals (where the behavior is linear) and large signals (where the behavior is nonlinear) because tanh(.) acts linearly when the inputs are small enough. Therefore, I have done these things:

1) extract the parameters of the linear filter (its Memory, and h parameters) for small signals

2) extract the K factor for small signals (by minimizing the NMSE error)

3) calculate z(t) for all signals

**4) Now, I have the inputs to the tanh(.), but I don't know what to do for the next step. Is the tanh(.) a nonlinear static function? Or it is dynamic? If it is dynamic, do I need to break it down to its Taylor series? if yes, how can I extract the parameters of each component?**

[image]

Here is the codes for the things I have done while I used the first two components of Taylor series of the tanh(.):

```
import scipy.io as sio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
fontSize=16
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# ########################### Extraction ######################################
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# Parameters

M_small = 3
M_first_Component = 5
M_second_Component = 3
power = 3
time = sio.loadmat('t.mat')
t = time['t']
x_True = sio.loadmat('x.mat')
x_True = x_True['x']
y_True = sio.loadmat('y.mat')
y_True = y_True['y']
# ###################### Extraction of small signal response ##################
# linear dynamic section
x_small_True_input = x_True[0:20000]
y_small_True_output = y_True[0:20000]
t_small_True = t[0:20000]
#
#for k in np.arange (1, 20, 0.1):
k=2.000999999999989 # I have achieved changed it with a "for" loop. The calculated the error. for this value of k, the error becomes minimum.
A_small_extraction = np.zeros([len(x_small_True_input), M_small])
for n in range(M_small, len(x_small_True_input)):
    for m in range(0, M_small):
        A_small_extraction[n, m] = x_small_True_input[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_small):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_small_extraction[m, j] = x_small_True_input[m-j]

h_small = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A_small_extraction.transpose(), A_small_extraction)),
    A_small_extraction.transpose()), y_small_True_output)
#print("Parameters of the linear filter (FIR) for small inputs are as follows: \n", h_small)
#print("*************")
Z_small = np.dot(A_small_extraction, h_small)
y_small = k * Z_small
error = y_small_True_output - y_small
NMSE=10*np.log10((np.sum(error**2))/(np.sum(y_small_True_output**2)))
correlation = np.mean(y_small_True_output*y_small) / np.sqrt(np.mean(y_small**2)*np.mean(y_small**2))
print("K value is: ", k)
#print("correlation: ", correlation)
print("NMSE for small signals: ",NMSE)
print("*****************")
######################  response to all input signals  ##################
A_all = np.zeros([len(x_True), M_small])
for n in range(M_small, len(x_True)):
    for m in range(0, M_small):
        A_all[n, m] = x_True[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_small):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_all[m, j] = x_True[m-j]
Z_all = np.dot(A_all, h_small)

##################### Non linear static section: y(t)=kZ(t)-(1/3)Z(t)^3 ##################### 
########## first component
A_small_first_Component = np.zeros([len(Z_small), M_first_Component])
for n in range(M_first_Component, len(Z_small)):
    for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
        A_small_first_Component[n, m] =  Z_small[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_small_first_Component[m, j] =  Z_small[m-j]
h_small_first_Component = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A_small_first_Component.transpose(), A_small_first_Component)),
    A_small_first_Component.transpose()), y_small_True_output)   
########## achieve the output of the first component for its all inputs, Z(t)
A_all_first_Component = np.zeros([len(Z_all), M_first_Component])
for n in range(M_first_Component, len(Z_all)):
    for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
        A_all_first_Component[n, m] =  Z_all[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_all_first_Component[m, j] = Z_all[m-j]  
y_first_for_all = np.dot(A_all_first_Component, h_small_first_Component)

########## second component
A_second_Component_all = np.zeros([len(Z_all), (power+1)*M_second_Component])
for n in range(M_second_Component, len(Z_all)):
    index = 0
    for m in range(0, M_second_Component):
        for PowerFactor in range(0, power+1):
            A_second_Component_all[n, index] =  Z_all[n-m]**PowerFactor
            index = index+1
for m in range(0, M_second_Component):
    index = 0
    for j in range(0, m):
        for PowerFactor in range(0, power+1):
            A_second_Component_all[m, index] =  Z_all[m-j]**PowerFactor
            index = index + 1   
h_all_second_Component = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A_second_Component_all.transpose(), A_second_Component_all)),
    A_second_Component_all.transpose()), y_True) 
########## achieve the output of the second component for its all inputs, Z(t)  
y_second_for_all = np.dot(A_second_Component_all, h_all_second_Component)
y_second_for_all = y_first_for_all - y_True            
########## sum first and second components to achieve the output        
Y_first_second_component=((k)*y_first_for_all)-((k/3)*y_second_for_all)

###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# ########################### Validation ######################################
###############################################################################
############################################################################### 
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
x_val_True = sio.loadmat('x_val.mat')
x_val_True = x_val_True['x_val']

y_val_True = sio.loadmat('y_val.mat')
y_val_True = y_val_True['y_val']

##################### linear dynamic filter section
A_val_linear_filter = np.zeros([len(x_val_True), M_small])
for n in range(M_small, len(x_val_True)):
    for m in range(0, M_small):
        A_val_linear_filter[n, m] =  x_val_True[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_small):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_val_linear_filter[m, j] =  x_val_True[m-j]
z_val = np.dot(A_val_linear_filter, h_small)

##################### Non linear tanh section
#first component
A_all_first_Component_val = np.zeros([len(z_val), M_first_Component])
for n in range(M_first_Component, len(z_val)):
    for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
        A_all_first_Component_val[n, m] =  z_val[n-m]
for m in range(0, M_first_Component):
    for j in range(0, m):
        A_all_first_Component_val[m, j] =  z_val[m-j]  
y_first_for_all_val = np.dot(A_all_first_Component_val, h_small_first_Component)
#second component
A_second_Component_all_val = np.zeros([len(z_val), (power+1)*M_second_Component])
for n in range(M_second_Component, len(z_val)):
    index = 0
    for m in range(0, M_second_Component):
        for PowerFactor in range(0, power+1):
            A_second_Component_all_val[n, index] =  z_val[n-m]**PowerFactor
            index = index+1
for m in range(0, M_second_Component):
    index = 0
    for j in range(0, m):
        for PowerFactor in range(0, power+1):
            A_second_Component_all_val[m, index] =  z_val[m-j]**PowerFactor
            index = index + 1 
y_second_for_all_val = np.dot(A_second_Component_all_val, h_all_second_Component)
y_second_for_all_val = y_first_for_all_val - y_True  
# Output of the Non linear tanh section
Y_first_and_second_components_val=((k)*y_first_for_all_val)-((k/3)*y_second_for_all_val)

############## Output of the whole system
Y_output_of_the_system_val = Y_first_and_second_components_val

error = y_val_True-Y_output_of_the_system_val
NMSE=10*np.log10((np.sum(error**2))/(np.sum(y_val_True**2)))
correlation = np.mean(y_val_True*Y_output_of_the_system_val) / np.sqrt(np.mean(y_val_True**2)*np.mean(Y_output_of_the_system_val**2))

print("Validation: K value is: ", k)
print("Validation: correlation: ", correlation)
print("Validation: NMSE: ",NMSE)
print("******** END **********")


###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# ############################# Plotting ######################################
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # create a new figure with a default 111 subplot
ax.plot(x_True, y_True)
plt.xlabel('x - input', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.ylabel('y - output', fontsize=fontSize)

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 7, loc=4) # zoom-factor: 2.5, location: lower-right
axins.plot(x_True, y_True)
axins.plot(x_small_True_input, y_small_True_output)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = -1, 1, -.8, .8 # specify the limits
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2) # apply the x-limits
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2) # apply the y-limits
plt.yticks(visible=False)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
plt.savefig('dynamicSystem_Inlet.pdf')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_True,y_True)
plt.plot(x_small_True_input,y_small_True_output,':')
plt.xlabel('x - input', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.ylabel('y - output', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.savefig('dynamicSystem.pdf')


fig, ax = plt.subplots() # create a new figure with a default 111 subplot
ax.plot(t, y_val_True, label='Validation signal')
ax.plot(t, Y_output_of_the_system_val,':', label='Model output')
ax.plot(t, error, label='Model error')
plt.xlabel('time', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.ylabel('amplitude', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.legend()

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 5, loc=3) # zoom-factor: 2.5, location: upper-left
axins.plot(t, y_val_True, label='Validation signal')
axins.plot(t, Y_output_of_the_system_val,':', label='Model output')
axins.plot(t, error, label='Model error')
x1, x2, y1, y2 = .0002, .000205, -.0145, .018 # specify the limits
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2) # apply the x-limits
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2) # apply the y-limits
plt.yticks(visible=False)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
plt.savefig('outputWithError_Inlet.pdf')


fig, ax = plt.subplots() # create a new figure with a default 111 subplot
ax.plot(x_val_True, y_val_True, label='Validation signal')
ax.plot(x_val_True, Y_output_of_the_system_val, ':', label='Model output')
plt.xlabel('x - input', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.ylabel('y - output', fontsize=fontSize)
plt.legend()

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 3, loc=4) # zoom-factor: 2.5, location: upper-left
axins.plot(x_val_True, y_val_True, label='Validation signal')
axins.plot(x_val_True, Y_output_of_the_system_val, ':', label='Model output')
x1, x2, y1, y2 = -.22, -.1, .05, .35 # specify the limits
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2) # apply the x-limits
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2) # apply the y-limits
plt.yticks(visible=False)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
```

Comment: NMSE : Something mean square error?

Comment: Yes, NMSE stands for normalized mean square error

Comment: Can you refer to a reference? I think that I can help you.